# Как красиво добавить много тегов с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например чтобы добиться этого

```
<div class="block">
<div class="title">
Тест из переменной "title"
</div>
<pre> Текст из переменной "text"</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как красиво добавить много тегов с помощью jquery?

Вот такой вариант добаления

```js
var ar = ['Тест из переменной "title"', 'Текст из переменной "text"'];

var div = $('<div/>', {
  class: 'block'
}) // Родительский елемент
var ddiv = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'title',
    text: ar[0]
  }) // Добавляет child element
  .add('<pre/>', {
    text: ar[1]
  }) // Добавляет child element
div.append(ddiv);
//----------------------------------------------------------------
/**** Если так нарвиться больше можно и так
div.append(
   $('<div/>', {class: 'title', text: ar[0]})
   .add('<pre/>', {text: ar[1]})
);

*/
// Добавляет все остальное   
$('.container').append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>

<!--
<div class="block">
  <div class="title">
    Тест из переменной "title"
  </div>
  <pre> Текст из переменной "text"</pre>
</div>
-->
```

Comment: @IvanZ Не за что. галочку отметьте, если то что вам нужно =)

Comment: Небольшая проблема,они не вложены друг в друга,https://jsfiddle.net/b9rjpufh/2/ ,все должно быть вложено в "note"

Comment: @IvanZ исправил.

Comment: Теперь точно спасибо)